# How to compare two nested array for difference?

Tags: arrays, typescript, compare

I want to compare two nested array for their change in length.
The comparison should be deep to their child element length.

Comment: Pleases tell in detail what are you  trying to achieve and show what have you tried?

Comment: I have a nested array. I could push item to the both root object and child object. so i want to compare between my initial array and new array if their length differ in any level root and child

Answer (score 0):

You should do looping for parent list and a single value search in child object list by linq query. Like this:

```
For(i = 0; i <= list1.count; i++)
{
  var a = list2.where(x => x.key == list1[i]);   // that is the linq query
}
```

I think you understand.